# Alternative proof of showing that d(x)=dist(x,A) is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

"Let A be a fixed nonempty subset of $\Bbb{R^m}$, let d: $\Bbb{R^m}\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined by d(x)=dist(x,A). Prove the function d is continuous on $\Bbb{R^m}$."

Here is the question and I made a proof that looks relatively easy and I think I'm doing a mistake somewhere. Here is my proof:

Let $\alpha$$\in$$\Bbb{R^m}$. Let $\varepsilon$>o be given.

I want to show that difference between d(x)-d($\alpha$) is small when |x-$\alpha$| is small. By triangle inequality, we have dist(x,A)$\le$dist(x,$\alpha$)+dist($\alpha$,A) (I know now that elements of A are not same in each side of inequality but still it should hold.)

This is same as |dist(x,A)-dist($\alpha$,A)|$\le$dist(x,$\alpha$). And we have dist(x,$\alpha$)=|x-$\alpha$|. So when we let |x-$\alpha$|<$\ell$ and let $\ell$=$\varepsilon$/2, we get

|d(x)-d($\alpha$)|=|dist(x,A)-dist($\alpha$,A)|$\le$dist(x,$\alpha$)<$\ell$=$\varepsilon$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I don't understand where $\alpha$ is coming from. Do you want $\alpha \in A$? Anyway, the idea is that if $y$ is a distance $\epsilon$ from $x,$ then $y$ is at most a distance of $\epsilon + d(x,A)$ from $A,$ since one route to getting from $y$ to $A$ is to go from $y$ to $x$ (a distance of $\epsilon)$ and then from $x$ to $A.$ (Of course, there might be a shorter route in getting from $y$ to $A.)$ A little care needs to be taken in writing this up rigorously if $A$ is not a closed set, since in this case there might not be a point in $A$ that is exactly a distance of $d(x,A)$ from $x.$

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate on why
$$
\text{dist}(x, A) \le d(x, \alpha) + \text{dist}(\alpha, A).
$$
Otherwise, the proof is almost correct: you wrote $\ell = \varepsilon$ where you mean to write $\ell < \varepsilon$.